# Finding a lost friend in a haunted mansion

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence

Whilst staying in a large haunted mansion, Mervin had carelessly lost his friend Debs.  She was nowhere to be found, and wasn't answering his calls.  Instead of finding her, he discovered this sequence of numbers, etched in dust.  Mervin feared that this was the work of one of the ghosts who haunted this mansion, however if these ghosts did indeed exist, they were helpful ghosts.

57007

3563

1027309

10

1027565

3053

What are the ghosts trying to tell Mervin?

---

Clue:

> Mervin is a wizard, do some research on him and the answer may reveal itself.

Comment: Given the clue, should we add the "knowledge" tag ?

Comment: Sure, I am not 100% sure this is tagged correctly anyway, if you can think of any other tags please let me know... This is my first question/puzzle here, so any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I googled Mervin wizard and the first link mentioned

> Hexadecimals. I then converted each number from base 10 to hex and the message spelled out "DEAF DEB FACED A FADED BED". The ghosts are trying to tell Mervin that Debs is deaf and can't hear his calls, and where to find her.